# Spring Data JPA Hibernate Implementing Optimistic Locking on DTOS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

Every time I save my a data from the form. It will always come first from the DTO.

So from my thymeleaf template/Controller. I use this method to save my entity

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute CollectionDTO collectionDTO){
    Collection collection = collectionService.save(collectionDTO);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/collection/view/"+collection.getId());
}
```

And this is the CollectionService.save

```
@Override
public Collection save(CollectionDTO collectionDTO) {
    Collection collection;
    if(collectionDTO.getId() != null){
        collection = collectionRepo.findOne(collectionDTO.getId());
        mapper.map(collectionDTO, collection);
    }else{
        collection = mapper.map(collectionDTO,Collection.class);

    }
    collection = collectionRepo.save(collection);
    return collection;
}
```

The mapper.map basically maps the contents from the DTO to the Model.

The Collection Entity is a little bit like this

```
public class Collection{

  @Version
  private long version;
}
```

Have I missed anything?

Comment: You are probably trying to save an older version.  Look at the version num from mapper.map and compare it to the version number in the database.

Comment: I was expecting it to throw an exception

Comment: What is the version number in the database when you're trying to save it?  What is the version number of the object you are trying to update/persist?